# Performance issue in resizing listview column for huge data in wpf

Tags: wpf, performance, listview

I have Listview with below properties :

VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"

Everything works normally but it takes 2-3 seconds when i maximize or resize the window with huge data in Listview.

Is there any solution to that without Virtualization?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your *ListView* inside a *ScrollViewer*

Comment: Still have performance issue when i will maximize or resize the window.

Comment: can you post the xaml?